# I am not able to play Youtube video in Videoview

Tags: android, video, youtube, youtube-api, android-videoview

I want to play youtube video in videoview for that i am successfully able to get rtsp link. Link is mention below

```
rtsp://r7---sn-a5m7zu7d.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk9hy-aQFCphhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

When I start playing it show some error like this `error (1, -2147483648)`.

Comment: Can you upload your code please ?

Comment: Thanks i am successfully able to play this video

Comment: nice, what changes you made ?

Comment: Actually emulator is not supporting this format. And I am using s3 emulator

Answer (score 1):

The `error (1, -2147483648)`refers that your device is not able to play such format. So instead of that version's .3gp you can try other format.